# Toad for MySQL connection problems (Win 7 to Linux)

Tags: mysql, windows-7, toad

I have a MySQL instance running on a Linux box, and a Mac which also has Win7 (Bootcamp/VMWare). I can connect to the MySQL db from Navcat Lite for Mac with no problems, however, I prefer Toad. I installed Toad for MySQL for Win7 but it just CANNOT connect to the db. I installed ODBC for MySQL and it CAN successfully connect to the db, so it's not a firewall issue (I also tried disabling the firewall)

Here is a quick summary of what I see:

1. MySQL db running on Linux box, within my network, port 3306
2. Mac can successfully connect to the db through Navcat Lite
3. Toad for MySQL (Win 7) CANNOT connect to the db using a TCP connection (tried increasing connection timeout to 30 sec)
4. ODBC Driver for MySQL (Win 7) CAN connect to the db using the same credentials

Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the error that Toad throws:

System.TimeoutException
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: I was going to migrate this, but, it is a question about a development tool and questions about development tools are on-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Check this bug report. Might be what you are facing.

link:
http://toadformysql.com/thread.jspa?threadID=32380

Taking in account your recent outcome from the packet sniffing, i do believe it is related to this bug report.

Toad seems to use the .net framework, according to [the release notes](http://dev.toadformysql.com/releasenotes/latest/ToadforMySQL_ReleaseNotes.htm) it requires version 3.5 to be installed and the security policy set to unrestricted.

So, do you have .net 3.5 installed? if so, can you try to run toad as administrator?

PS: to set the security policy and i'm quoting from the link above:

> To run Toad, the .NET security policy must be set to Unrestricted. To modify the security policy:
>
> - Select Control Panel from the Windows Start menu.
> - Double-click Administrative Tools.
> - Double-click Microsoft .NET Framework version Configuration.
> - Select My Computer, and then select the Runtime Security Policy
>     node.
> - Select Evaluate Assembly from the list of tasks in the right panel,
>     and locate and select Toad.exe in the File field.
> - Click Next and set the permission to Unrestricted.

Hope it helps, keep providing information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It's not a privileges issue either, since both ODBC and HeidiSQL (another SQL GUI Tool) can connect successfully

Comment: I guess you need to break down the issues into parts then. with a packet sniffer check if any data goes forth and back to the server, when you attempt to login with toad. if you use wireshark (just tested here) it will make it easier to understand MySQL packets as you get info on what each request made (eg. "Login request user=root"; "Server greeting proto=10 ..."; "Response Error 1045"). Wireshark can be downloaded [here](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)

Comment: Thanks! I did the packet sniff, and the last packet that the MySQL server sent was a "Server Greeting proto=10 Version=4.1.22". After that the client should send a login request, but I never saw that packet. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: I also installed a 4.x version of Toad for MySQL to see if that would make things better. Still having the same issue, but instead of getting the long error dump I get this message: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Comment: I've updated my answer taking into account the additional information you've provided.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly I read the note about the .NET Framework requirement. I installed 4.0, but the 3.5 executable just would not run so I abandoned it. I will try again and report back!

Comment: I realized I can't install .NET 3.5 because it's already included with Windows 7. It just needs to be activated, which I did. Microsoft .NET Framework version Configuration does not appear in the Control Panel though. I tried searching for Mscorcfg.msc and even installed the Microsoft SDK, but couldn't get to the configuration for .NET 3.5. The chase continues! Regardless, shouldn't Toad work "out of the box" for Win 7 without requiring these tweaks?

Comment: I don't know then. Because it's already verified that its not a mysql credentials issue and that the server is actually responding i believe that in StackExchange Super User there will be more users who can answer this. although i have no use for toad, i installed in a win7 32bit VM and it worked without issues. Maybe an admin will migrate this question and you'll get better support.

Comment: Thanks! I also had this thread going and it looks like they are going to make a tweak that could solve the issue: http://www.toadformysql.com/thread.jspa?messageID=126249&#126249

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with one my MySQL installations. I am able to connect using MySQL Workbench, but Toad for MySQL does not connect. Also, every application I created using MySQL .NET Connector also times out.

The solution I found was to connect the machines to the Internet and they connect instantly. I believe it has to do with the Connector and not Toad. Updating to a version beyond 5 should help.

Answer (score 0):

Using freeware Toad for MySQL 8.0.0.296 (64 bit), instead using connection type TCP, use connection type SSH, insert database data like Host IP, user, password, default database and port. Also add SSH port, SSH Host IP, SSH user and password. Toad will emulate onnection directly to SSH console, the interface is the same, it works very fine, the error "Character set 'utf8mb3' is not supported by .Net Framework"  is gone.